# How to disable sundays in uikit(getuikit) datepicker?

Tags: frontend, getuikit

I am having difficulty disabling sundays in the datepicker for uikit. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in uikit datepicker, but you can try to do this yourself. Try to grab the uikit events of calendar, look into docs - it is show.uk.datepicker and update.uk.datepicker. See what's happening in dom. When you see datepicker, run function that disables links inside two last childs(saturday and sunday by default) of tr < td inside calendar table.

```
$('.uk-datepicker-table td:nth-child(6), .uk-datepicker-table td:nth-child(7)').each(function() {
    var replace = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(replace).addClass('my-mute-class');
});
```

Comment: I know this is cheap solution, but couldn't invent anything faster